# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.recipes is undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux

I am just trying to delete an item on my page. When I delete the item I get this **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.recipes is undefined** message pointing to my reducer. When I refresh my page, the object is gone and the error disappears. The question is what is causing this error prior to the item deleting?

*This is what happens after I click delete button, when I refresh the page the object is gone.*
[image]

```
 case 'DELETING_RECIPE_START': 
            return {
            ...state.recipes, 
            loading: true 
            }

        case 'DELETE_RECIPE_SUCCESS':
            
This line ----->  const recipes = state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== action.payload.recipeId)
            
            return {
                ...state, recipes,
               loading: false
            
            }
```

I was told in this case is to check your delete action on the backend. When I plugged in byebug, It is showing me which object am trying to delete, so hopefully its nothing there I need to worry about.

```
def destroy
      
        recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
        
        unless recipe.nil?
      
          recipe.destroy
          render json: recipe
        else
          render json: { error: "Property not found" }, status: 404
        end
    end
```

I did modify my delete action to the **thunk** asynchronous conventions, and I hope it's structured correctly. I will note when I run debugger before the return(dispatch) this issue with my error seems to happen after the **return(dispatch)** line.

```
export const deleteRecipe = (recipeId) =>{
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:3001`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`
    debugger
    return (dispatch) => {
        
        dispatch({ type: "DELETING_RECIPE_START" })
        fetch(`${RECIPES_URL}/${recipeId}`,{method: 'DELETE'})
          .then(response =>{return response.json()})
          .then(recipeId =>  dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_RECIPE_SUCCESS', payload: recipeId }))
          .catch((error) => console.log.error(error))
    };

}
```

Last here is my Recipe component with the delete button and the event handler associated.

```
class Recipe extends Component {
   
    handleOnClick(){
        this.props.deleteRecipe(this.props.recipe.id);
      }

    render(){
        
        return(
            <div>
            <h3>Name: {this.props.recipe.name}</h3>
            <p>Category:{this.props.recipe.category_id}</p>
            <p>Chef Name: {this.props.recipe.chef_name}</p>
            <p>Origin: {this.props.recipe.origin}</p>
            <p>Ingredients: {this.props.recipe.ingredients}</p>
            <button onClick={()=>this.handleOnClick()}>Delete</button>
            </div>
             
        )
    }

}

export default Recipe
```

What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in the solution. I credit my cohort lead for this. There was some restructuring involved.

When debugger is placed in my it’ll indicate that a key is not provided for recipes…well here is what it meant.

My DELETE_RECIPE_START case was like this at first

```
case 'DELETING_RECIPE_START': 
            return {
            
            ...state.recipes, 
            loading: true 
            }
```

It needed to look likes this

```
case 'DELETING_RECIPE_START': 
            return {
            
            recipe:[...state.recipes], 
            loading: true 
            }
```

The recipe is the key while its current state is the value

The next part blew my mind…The delete action did not need a json response. You are only telling it to delete an id and that's it.

```
export const deleteRecipe = (recipeId) =>{
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:3001`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`

    
   
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(`${RECIPES_URL}/${recipeId}`, { method: 'DELETE' })
            .then(() => {
                return dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_RECIPE_SUCCESS', payload: recipeId })
            });
    };

}
```

I am really trying to get better at this but I enjoy the fact that I am learning.